# IPv6 address copy optimization in C

Tags: c, linux, ipv6, glibc, memcpy

since `memcpy` should be highly optimized nowadays, does it still make sense to optimize the copy of Ipv6 addresses using explicit loop unrolling ?

```
#include <netinet/in.h>

struct in6_addr IP_1;
struct in6_addr IP_2;
;
;
IP2.__in6_u.__u6_addr32[0] = IP1.__in6_u.__u6_addr32[0];
IP2.__in6_u.__u6_addr32[1] = IP1.__in6_u.__u6_addr32[1];
IP2.__in6_u.__u6_addr32[2] = IP1.__in6_u.__u6_addr32[2];
IP2.__in6_u.__u6_addr32[3] = IP1.__in6_u.__u6_addr32[3];
```

Note that the code above is best suited for 32-bit architectures.

Is there a best practice I do not know ?

Comment: According to my tests with GCC, your code is slower than both `memcpy` and `IP2=IP1`.  Both `memcpy` and `IP2=IP1` generate the same code, with no loop and only *two* copy assignments instead of four.

Comment: Yep, I expect in the best case two 64-bit assignments.

Comment: Explicit loop unrolling is pointless anyway. Any half-decent compiler will unroll a loop for you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should just do `IP2 = IP1;`, and let the compiler deal with it.

Comment: I always forget the possibility to assign directly one struct to another of the same type.